# Why is my CoreGraphics shape not showing a border?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

This is the code I have:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(context, rect);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [BUTTON_COLOR CGColor]);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);

int radius = CORNER_RADIUS;

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, self.frame.size.height / 2);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, POINT_WIDTH, self.frame.size.height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width - radius, 
                            rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);
CGContextAddArc(context, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width - radius, 
                    rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - radius, radius, M_PI / 2, 0.0f, 1);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y + radius);
CGContextAddArc(context, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width - radius, rect.origin.y + radius, 
                    radius, 0.0f, -M_PI / 2, 1);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, POINT_WIDTH, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, self.frame.size.height / 2);

CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

Why is it not drawing a border around the shape?

EDIT: Now it draws the shape, thanks to changing the last line, but it draws an extra line around it, like this:

http://cl.ly/0u0e051a060m161u0n08

Comment: Linking a picture might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke)` instead of `CGContextFillPath()` and `CGContextStrokePath()`.

The thing is, after the first call to `CGContextFillPath()` or `CGContextStrokePath()` the context's path is cleared, so the second call does not have a path to work with.

Comment: This draws the line, but the problem is, it also draws it around the shape, like this: http://cl.ly/0u0e051a060m161u0n08

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you sure you haven't set the corner radius and border for the view (or its superview)? The outer border is definitely drawn elsewhere.